# the number of set T

Tags: combinatorics

A={1,2,3...,n} and let T is subset of P(A)

then T satisfies following properties

(1) empty set is element of T

(2) If Y is element of T then Y^c is also element of T

(3) if X,Y are elements of T then union of X,Y is also element of T

How many T's are there?

I have done some calculations, 1 for n = 1, 2 for n = 2, 5 for n = 3, 15 for n = 4

and I try to use recurrence formula..but fail..

How do I get a closed-form??

Comment: Notice that for any fixed $j$ you can consider the smallest set that contains $j$, let us denote it by $A_j$. It exists since if there are $A_1$ and $A'_1$ with the same number of elements and both containing $j$, then their intersection must be in $T$ and have less elements. Thus, you have a decomposition of $A$ into disjoint sets.

Comment: yeah, i agree union of A1..An is A ..but how do i prove each other disjoint?

Answer (score 1):

Each and every $T$ corresponds to a [partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of $A$. Namely, if $S\subseteq P(A)$ is a partitioning, then $$T = \{\cup S'\ : S' \subseteq S\}$$
is the corresponding subset of $P(A)$, and there are no others (for arbitrary $T$, consider its nonempty elements that are minimal with respect to inclusion - these form a partitioning of $A$, and this idea is already in the comments). So you're seeking for [these numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Comment: It was very helpful!!